# Problems when making a test with RSpec and Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

Im new to Capybara and RSpec code and Im facing some weird problems.

I have a resource called bill_of_lading. In my rake routes I got:

```
 bill_of_ladings GET    /bill_of_ladings(.:format)                               bill_of_ladings#index
                                 POST   /bill_of_ladings(.:format)                               bill_of_ladings#create
              new_bill_of_lading GET    /bill_of_ladings/new(.:format)                           bill_of_ladings#new
             edit_bill_of_lading GET    /bill_of_ladings/:id/edit(.:format)                      bill_of_ladings#edit
                  bill_of_lading GET    /bill_of_ladings/:id(.:format)                           bill_of_ladings#show
                                 PUT    /bill_of_ladings/:id(.:format)                           bill_of_ladings#update
                                 DELETE /bill_of_ladings/:id(.:format)                           bill_of_ladings#destroy
```

In my Rspec im trying to test a creation of a new Bill Of Lading (everything works on the webapp)

This is my test scenario:

```
RSpec.feature "Creating Bill of Lading" do
    scenario "A user creates a new Bill of Lading" do

    visit('/bill_of_ladings')

    click_link "New Bill of Lading"
end
```

And in my bill_of_ladding/index.erb I have:

```
<%=link_to "New Bill of Lading",new_bill_of_lading_path(),:title => "New Bill of Lading",:class => "btn btn-primary"%>
```

When I run the rspec I got this error:

Failures:

```
  1) Creating Bill of Lading A user creates a new Bill of Lading
     Failure/Error: click_link "New Bill of Lading"
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find link "New Bill of Lading"
```

What Im doing wrong here?

Comment: `bill_of_ladding/index.erb` maybe its because of this typo and the renderer runs into an issue and capybara just cant find the element its looking for?

Comment: your routes say that when you visit `localhost/bill_of_laddings` you get a 404. See the double `d`?

Comment: It was a typo error on the comment Buddy. On the Question I think that everything looks fine I guess.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was:

I put a debug line to check the current_path. And it gets:

---

/spud/user_session/new

---

So, of course, the page was being redirected to a login page, and didnt found the link.

Closing the question.